# Which protocol should I use to exchange files between multiple nodes?

Tags: go, distributed-computing, distributed-system, file-sharing, system-design

I have multiple nodes. Node is just a linux or windows server. Also I have one master node. The master node is manager of process of file sharing.

This images shows process of communication:
[image]

So, I try to choose some protocol for this system, which I can implement (or just use some existing implementation). I need a file sharing protocol. I mean checking the checksum, managing a Internet bandwidth, managing the process of data exchange.

File is just a binary data. File size is approximately 1-10 MB. The number of files in the system is approximately 1 million. 90% of all requests are write requests.

Comment: You can use SMB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web servers are designed to serve files (amongst other things).

I would recommend you use the http protocol and use https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer which requires just a few lines of code to set up.

If you need secure transmission then use https, also available with FileServer: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ListenAndServeTLS